# How to execute multiple Firebase request and receive a callback when all requests are finished?

Tags: javascript, firebase, babeljs

I want to execute these three Firebase requests in parallel and receive a callback when all requests are finished. I thought I can use await*, but it seems it is not supported in Babel. I am not worried about data consistency, as I am writing to/updating different firebase data nodes.

I am using babel.

```
await* Promise.all([
  firebaseRef1.push(data1),
  firebaseRef2.push(data2),
  firebaseRef3.push(data3)
]);
// all three are finished
```

which initially was this:

```
const [first, second, third] = await* Promise.all([
  firebaseRef1.push(data1),
  firebaseRef2.push(data2),
  firebaseRef3.push(data3)
]);
// all three are finished
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`push()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html) does not return a promise, so you'd have to use it's callback to resolve or reject one of your own.

```
const allPushes = Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebaseRef1.push(data1, error => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve();
    });
  }),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebaseRef2.push(data2, error => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve();
    });
  }),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebaseRef3.push(data3, error => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve();
    });
  })
]);

allPushes.then(() => {
  // all three are finished
}, error => {
  // A push failed
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but just to note that with the Firebase model it's not always necessary to care about completions because it is not request/response.

Answer (score 1):

Anid Monsur's answer is 100% right.

But, it's important to note here that Firebase uses WebSockets. This means that there are no actual **requests**. In your case it's perfectly fine to just call `.push()` and not worry about the callback.

```
firebaseRef1.push(data1);
firebaseRef2.push(data2);
firebaseRef3.push(data3);
```

It's in the listeners that you'll know the callback was completed.

```
firebaseRef1.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
firebaseRef2.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
firebaseRef3.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```